# What non-lane minion units are considered "minions"?

Tags: league-of-legends

For the purposes of Banner of Command, Baron Buff, and Elixir of Ruin,

What else can be affected by them that aren't lane minions?

Do they all stack?

Comment: minions only refers to the creeps that go down the lane. Other creatures (wolves, gromp, dragon, etc) are usually referred to as monsters

Comment: i'm talking about things like zyra plants, heimer turrets...., old banner interacted with them and the banner stated it affected minions, hence the non-lane minons, take into account that yuuki changed my question title , it was before the chamge what champion skills are considered minions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Lane minions" is a redundant term, because all minions move down a lane, and there are no "non-lane minions". Therefore, whenever an effect refers to minions, it means nothing else but the melee, caster, and siege minions that spawn every 30 seconds.

Baron buff, Banner of Command, and Elixier of Ruin do stack their effects on minions. You can have a banner-promoted minion that is affected by all 3 minion buff auras.

Comment: it is known that before the chamge banner of command affected heimerdinger turrets and zyras plant. Mayby lane minions can sound rendudant but it clarifies many things, malzahar minions are called minions too and they don't have to be in lane

Comment: If you read the current text of Banner, you will find it says that its aura affects "allies", not "minions"; allies means everyone on your side, i.e. champions, minions, and all kinds of summoned creatures, pets etc.. Also, Malzahar spawns "voidlings"; where are they referred to as minions?

Comment: I think you didn't understand my comment, I said before they changed it banner of command increased 15% minion damage and that increase affected malzahar voidlings, heimer turrets and zyra plants. I had a tipo and put chamge instead of change.

Comment: What is the point of asking about previous versions of the item and how terms were used in the past? In my answer I explained what the current meaning of "minion" is, and the current Banner also correctly makes that distinction.

Comment: I'm not asking about previous version. I'm asking about the version we have now and its interactions, i'm only stating the not that old minion buff that affected non-lane minions like zyra plants or heimer turrets. So taking into account an old interaction i am asking if what we have now , the specific options affect minions that aren't the caster,melee or siege minions that we have in lane

Comment: Just asking since it's related, are super minions considered lane minions? As far as I know they can't be affected by banner of command.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your second question, [this question (second answer)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/221071/113116) adressed the bonuses of Banner of Command and Baron buff added to each other.

[user 5061](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/108978/user-5061) also explains how he calculated the numbers.